# Objective-C UIWebView Not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using XCode 7 and iOS 9 and I added a UIWebView to my storyboard scene

and did the following:

Connected it to my header file and added the UIWebViewDelegate:

```
@interface LHPurchaseOrderDetail : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;
```

and then did this in my .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        
        [super viewDidLoad];
        
        NSLog(@"WebView : %@",_viewWeb);
        
        [_viewWeb setDelegate:self];
        
        NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
        
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
        
    }
```

and that NSLog returns this:

```
WebView : <UIWebView: 0x7a7e85a0; frame = (0 0; 240 128); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a7d8d90>>
```

I have these two methods:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViewIn {
        NSLog(@"web view did finish loading");
    }
```

and

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
    }
```

Error does not show up in my log, but web view did finish loading did

But the UIWebView does not appear. This is inside an Detail View Controller, this is a contraints issue with my storyboard, I don't know anything about contraints so you would have to be specific. What Am I doing wrong? Why isnt my UIWebView Appearing?

Here is an image of my storyboard:

[image]

Comment: That's a really small web view. Try making it larger and make sure it's not behind any other views.

Comment: i guess 240x128 is not a small frame @rmaddy

Comment: Are you sure it didn't appear? Have you tried inspecting if it really is there with Debug View Hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code,except you have to replace http with https.

This is the new thing introduced in ios9.

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

Comment: But the OP stated that there is no error and that it loaded. If ATS was blocking the `http:` URL, there would have been an error.

Comment: you are correct. I missed the OP saying about "this is a contraints issue with my storyboard" . But there is no way in iOS 9 to load http connections, without altering the plist!!!! As the OP failed to mention anything about ATS, I assumed, OP might have missed it.

Comment: does your view have any other view other than webview?

Comment: @Mr.T I have updated my question with an image of the storyboard scene

Comment: try changing the webveiw background color, and see it is there or not